# In "(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect", Parameter of rect are always integer

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics

I am trying to draw a pattern at runtime after clearing the old pattern in a given rect by calling he following:

```
[self setNeedsDisplayInRect:CGRectMake(10.25f, 10.56f, 13.34f, 15.66f)];
```

But when `- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect` is called the values for `rect` are manipulated. I get :

```
x=10 y=10 width=14 height=17.
```

Is it a desired behavior or am I missing something?

Comment: I would assume that you always need to redraw full pixels

Comment: But I need to start drawing from a position which might not be always absolute in the view. Is that also not possible?